# Open Silverlight website in mobile

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, mobile, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I have searched to see how to open website on a mobile device, which is built using Silverlight 4.0 and VS 2010. Is it possible to open website on a mobile which is build using Silverlight 4.0 or 5.0?

Answer (score 2):

There are no Silverlight plugins for those mobile devices (or more specifically their browser+operating systems). Silverlight support for mobile was abandoned when iPhone refused to allow plugins (Flash or Silverlight).

The only phones that really supports Silverlight are the Windows Phone 7 devices (which I must admit are very nice). *The downside is that they only support installed Silverlight applications, not via the provided version of Internet Explorer.*

Comment: then is there any other way to open silverlight website inside mentioned devices?? Thank you so much for answering

Comment: @Pritesh: The only theoretical way would be to supply a live video of it being run on a remote server, and supply mouse clicks to the server, but that is impractical... so basically no. You can't use Silverlight on them.

Comment: oh....its a big tragedy....for me(after all for silverlight team)........btw......thank you so much for answering

Comment: WP7 app model uses Silverlight, but does its browser (some flavor of IE) support Silverlight? I don't think so.